# Understanding s3 PutBucketLogging action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

- A company uses multiple AWS accounts in a single AWS Region.
- A solutions architect is designing a solution to consolidate logs generated by Elastic Load Balancers (ELBs) in the AppDev, AppTest and AppProd accounts.
- The logs should be stored in an existing Amazon S3 bucket named s3-eib-logs in the central AWS account.
- The central account is used for log consolidation only and does not have ELBs deployed.

**Solution:**
Update the S3 bucket policy for the s3-elb-logs bucket to allow the s3 PutBucketLogging action for the central AWS account ID

**My Doubt:**
Here, `s3 PutBucketLogging` will only allow central AWS account to enable or modify the bucket logging configuration for the "s3-eib-logs" bucket. How the  `s3 PutBucketLogging` will allow to store consolidated logs from ELBs into the "s3-eib-logs" bucket?

Comment: You appear to have posted an incomplete AWS sample exam question. The answer is going to be a combination of the listed steps (that you haven't shown).

Answer (score 0):

Where is the solution from? It does seem incomplete.

Putbucketlogging from the aws documentation:

> Set the logging parameters for a bucket and to specify permissions for who can view and modify the logging parameters. All logs are saved to buckets in the same AWS Region as the source bucket. To set the logging status of a bucket, you must be the bucket owner.